# How to code svg layers so they appear in Inkscape layers drop down menu?

Tags: svg, d3.js, inkscape

I'am coding some svg for later Inkscape post-editing. Also, I have groups that I want to make appears as layer when in the drop down menu. But currently, when clicked, I just see `(root)` and nothing more while I actually have 12 layers which should produce 12 rows pilling up.

[image]

I currently do :

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("groupmode","layer")
    .attr({'id':'L1_borders','label':'L1_borders'})
```

But it doesn't work ([see & download](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/1.2_location_map/index.html)).

**How to code svg layers so they appear in Inkscape layers drop down menu ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Inkscape GUI, create a new layer, and inspecting it shows that, for some reasons, Inkscape adds the namespace "inkscape:" before few attibute's keys, such:

[image]

So the D3 code mirroring this behavior should rather be:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("inkscape:groupmode","layer")
    .attr({'id':'L1_borders','inkscape:label':'L1_borders'})
```

which annoys me because it's unlikely to be standard. Annoying.

Even that addition, actually, get cleaned up by D3js which I totally support in this audacious move !

Yet, i need these. I eventually made a tiny hack :

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr(":inkscape:groupmode","layer")
    .attr({'id':'L1_borders',':inkscape:label':'L1_borders'})
```

D3js cleans up the first `...:` and leaves the `inkscape:label`. It then works. By ex. When done on L0 & L1:

[image]

Layers are now accessible as clickable rows in the drop GUI layers down menu.

Oh, ugly naughty non-standard hack~~~

Comment: SVG has no concept of "layers".  That's why Inkscape uses its own namespace to store that information in attributes.

Comment: You should probably also add the namespace declaration `xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"` to your root `<svg>` element.

Comment: And to correctly add the namespace with d3, this is where you would use the `d3.ns.prefix` object to register your own namespace.